# Why does a local variable get initiated in if-else constructs but not in if-else-if constructs?

Tags: java, if-statement, initialization

So We know that a local variable has to be initialized in order to be used in if-else-if construct.
As an example, the following code will not compile.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String...args){
      double price= 11;
      String model ;
      if (price>10)
        {model ="smartphone";}
      else if  (price<=11) 
        {model="not smart phone";}
      System.out.println(model);
    }
}
```

But, if you change `else if  (price<=11)` to `else` or initialize the local variable String model to some random value, the code will compile successfully.
My question in this case is "why?"

Now, this was a question from a book and the explanation was:

"the local variable model is only declared, not initialized. The initialization
of the variable model is placed within the if and else-if constructs. If you initialize a variable within an if or else-if construct, the compiler can’t be sure whether these conditions will evaluate to true, resulting in no initialization of the local variable."

Even after the explanation, I still didn't understand two things,

1. I am not sure why variable model will confuse the compiler, since double price is 11 regardless of what model is.
2. How does it magically initialize the local variable when you put else at the end?

Comment: `price` is a variable and as such its value could be `variable`.  So in your code, there is no guarantee that either the `if` or the `else if` would be entered into

Comment: the last if condition could fail on 11.5 and as there is no else model will not be initialised,

Comment: @Joop for 11.5, surely the first condition is met. It'd fail for NaN, though.

Comment: The ultimate aim is to INITIALIZE "model". Only "if" or only "else if" wont guarantee initialization of variable "model" as the condition may never become true. But if you use if-else then compiler will be guaranteed that anyhow "model" will be going to initialize either in "if" or in "else"!

Comment: 1. because you have to initial the `model` before call by `System.out`.   2. because one of the conditions worked before calling `System.out`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`model` must be initialized before the `System.out.println(model);` statement in order for the code to pass compilation.

1. The compiler doesn't analyze the conditions of the if-else-if statements to determine whether one of them will always be met, so it can't be sure that either the if or else-if blocks are always executed, and therefore it can't be sure that `model` will be initialized prior to the `println` statement.
2. When you use an if-else construct, either the if or else block would be executed, so since both of them initialize `model`, it is guaranteed to be initialized prior to the `println` statement.